A/B Test for CTR without user-level data
Suppose I want to show two different ads and compare which one generates more clicks. By design I know that each user will see one of two ads at random every time s/he visits an external page where these ads are shown. And each user can see every ad many times and click on it as many times as s/he likes.
The problem is that I don't have reliable information to track users individually so I can't be sure how many impressions and clicks each user has had.
Result-wise it's not a problem because I want to know which ad generates more clicks per impression regardless of users. But to properly compare two ads as far as I understand I have to make some corrections because impressions are not independent events. If I understand correctly in this paper (https://alexdeng.github.io/public/files/wsdm2017-rup.pdf) there's a way to properly compute variance for a similar case (section 4.2 Corollary 4) and this variance may be bigger than naive variance assuming i.i.d for impressions. But this method assumes that I can track all users' impressions and clicks.
So what's the way to rigorously compare two ads in my case without user data?

If understood your data setup correctly, variance is not the only problem. There will also be bias of unknown direction from identity fragmentation. See  https://tesarylin.github.io/uploads/IFB.pdf. SUTVA does not hold here.

@dimitriy yes, you're right about identity fragmentation bias. That's why I'm trying to find a way to compare ads without relying on user data at all.

Take a look at the two bounding approaches in the paper. No idea if they would be feasible in your experiment.
